# Can you use a variable as a table key? [Lua]

Tags: lua

I want a user input as an `io.read` then I want use that variable as `key`  for a table. I have little knowledge of programming

Is this possible?

EDIT

For example

```
Alpha = {}

print("foo")
Table1 = io.read()

Table1 = tonumber


print(Alpha.Table1)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Show us what you've done so far.

Comment: If I input `foo`, do you mean use the string `"foo"` as the key, or the value of a variable named `foo`?

Comment: You already know `Alpha.Table1` is not what you want. It is shorthand for  `Alpha["Table1"]`. It can be used where the key is a string that can be an identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to put that variable in square brackets:

```
local input = io.read() -- get the value from the user
print(tbl[input]) -- access key in "tbl" based on value in "input"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
myTable= {"a", "b", "c"}
i = tonumber(io.read())
if i >= 1 and i <= #myTable then
    print(myTable[i])
end
```